# vue массив в массиве

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте, есть массив:

### [image: массив]

Код:

```
var content = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        data: data
    }
});
```

Все значений из массива выводятся, но как вывести значения из массива items который внутри data ? Состав items от меня не зависит, постоянно удаляются и добавляются строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблемы

```
v-for="i in item.items"
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Вывести значения из массива items можно например так:

```js
  var appVue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [{
        items: ['item 1 1', 'item 1 2', 'item 1 3', ]
      },
      {
        items: ['item 2 1', 'item 2 2', 'item 2 3', ]
      },
      {
        items: ['item 3 1', 'item 3 2', 'item 3 3', ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.data[0].items.push('new item')
    },
    remove() {
      this.data[0].items.pop()
    },
    set() {
      this.data[0].items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click=add>Добавить элемент</button>
  <button @click=remove>Удалить элемент</button>
  <button @click=set>Задать сразу массивом</button>
  <ul v-for="(Record, index) in data" :key="`Record-${index}`">
    <li><b>Record #{{index+1}}</b></li>
    <li v-for="(item, indexItem) in Record.items" :key="`item-${index}-${indexItem}`" v-text="item" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Состав items от меня не зависит, постоянно удаляются и добавляются строки.

Comment: Замечательно. Код от этого не меняется. Добавил кнопки, изменяющие массив. На самый самый крайний случай есть метод Vue.set (он же this.$set) Документация: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что информация в items парситься с апи и постоянно меняется, её надо просто вывести. Поступает массив дата, я от туда берётся никнейм пользователя таким способом: "{{ data.userName }}" и надо, что бы бралась информация ещё и с items которая для каждого пользователя разная.